# iPhone SDK Scrolling Game Area with Dragging Cards

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, uiscrollview

We are starting a new game and while I have a few months experience with iPhone SDK, I'm not quite sure the best approach to take for this project.

Basically, our card game requires more real estate than the iPhone screen allows.  What we ultimately need is about 480x600 pixels so some of our gameboard will be off the screen sometimes.   We will need to be able to take cards from one side of the screen and drag them to another.

For the past few days I've been trying different things, both using cocos2d and other tries using UIKit,  but haven't been able to come up with a good solution.  I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.   A UIScrollView with draggable UIImageViews inside of it seems to be a logical choice but its easier said than done.

Answer (score 0):

Download the free version of the "Words with Friends" app.  They use a 2-state zoomable game board with localized zooming and scrolling depending on what you are looking at.

How would that work for your game?